# Is there a C# equivalent for @FindAll in Java

Tags: c#, page-objects

Java's @FindAll allows the user to match at least one of the given criteria e.g.

```
@FindAll({
    @FindBy(className = "class1")
    @FindBy(className = "class2")
})
private List<WebElement> elementsWithEither_class1ORclass2
```

I would like to know if there's a C# implementation of this or how I could replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `FindsBy` attribute.

The code should look like:

```
[FindBy(How = How.Class, Using = "class1")]
[FindBy(How = How.Class, Using = "class2")]
private List<WebElement> elementsWithEither_class1ORclass2
```

You can find more information about using .NET attributes in the [Selenium .NET documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm)